# What values can $v-e+f$ attain if $G$ is a planar (non connected) graph?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a planar graph and choose planar representation.

If $G$ is connected, then according to [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula), we have $$v − e + f = 2,$$ were $v$ is the number of vertices, $e$ the number of edges and $f$ the number of regions bounded by edges, including the outer, infinitely large region.

I was wondering which values $v-e+f$ can assume if $G$ is planar, but not connected. After some drawing, I feel that it can be any integer larges than 1, but I cannot prove it.

Is there someone who can help me out?

Answer (score 4):

note that one of the *faces* of a planar graph is the unbounded region "outside" the graph. this is in common to the separate connected components, so you can then sum over components and obtain:

$$ v-e+f = 1 + C
$$
where $C$ is the number of connected components.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but I have a slight quibble with your reasoning.  It is not in general true that each component of a disconnected planar graph borders the outer region.

Comment: @Jim Belk could you elaborate a little, please, Jim? stimulated by your quibble i can already see that my naïve approach ignored the fact that one component might in fact be entirely enclosed in a face of another component - though the principle that its "exterior" face is already counted still holds. nonetheless it would be good to see how this glitch is properly dealt with. thanks for the provocation to insight.

Comment: As you point out, the problem is that one component of the graph may be contained within another component (or more generally there might be a whole tree of nested components).  There are a variety of ways around this problem: one option is to prove the formula inductively, using a Jordan curve to separate a disconnected graph into two batches of components;  another is to simply add edges until all of your inner regions are disks, note that each added edge reduced the number of components by one, and then apply your argument.

Comment: suggests looking at a sequence of endomorphisms and observing their effect on the desired index $v-e+f$. thus we may remove isolated vertices and trees, but each such operation reduces $v-e$ by $1$. a vertex of degree 2 can be deleted without changing the index. similarly for absorbtion of "danglers". I like the tree approach you suggest, and will have a think about this. many thanks for setting me on the right track here

Answer (score 2):

I believe $v-e+f\geq 2$. Given a planar graph $G$ with $v$ vertices, $e$ edges and $f$ faces and $c$ components, we can construct a new graph $G'$ by adding a new vertex $x$ and adding $c$ edges such that $x$ is connected to an arbitrary vertex on the "outside" of each component.

$G'$ is planar and have the same number of faces as $G$ ($G'$ can be drawn to look like a star with the components of $G$ taking the place of the end-vertices with $x$ the center). (*)

Moreover, $G'$ is connected so $(v+1)-(e+c)+f=2$. Hence $(v-e+f=1+c \geq 2)$.

P.S. I'm not entirely sure of the claim at (*) yet. Might need to think it through and if it's possible to give a better reason if it is indeed true.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply Euler's formula to each connected component. Beware of the exterior face!

You find: $\sum_i v_i - e_i + f_i = 2c$. And $\sum_i v_i = v, \sum_i e_i = e, \sum_i f_i = c + \sum_i (f_i - 1) = c + f - 1$.

Thus: $v - e + c + f - 1 = 2c$, which gives $v - e + f = c + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If we manage to "construct" a not connected graph with $v-e+f=1$, then we are done.

Let $G_1$ be a planner graph, thus $v-e+f=2$, now we add to this graph a graph $G_2$ which have only two vertices, $v_1,v_2$(which are not the vertices of $G_1$, of course) and one edge, that connected them and only them. So Euler characteristic($v-e+f$) of $G_1\cup G_2$ is $1$.

Now you can duplicate that $G$   $\ \ n$ times, to get  $v-e+f=n$.